# can't close picture in memory with Dispose

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i use this code for picture watermark and when i try to move or delete picture visual studio show this error :

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'E:\lian\Guest_Upload\upload\179caeff-3ebe-472a-9eda-aeda8ebbbd40.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

i try to release with
Dispose

or

GC.Collect()

or

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

but nothing happen.

please help me to resolve this issue

this is my code :

```
  Dim watermarkText As String = "Name"
    Dim watermarkText1 As String = "Nameeeee1111"

    'Get the file name.
    Dim fileName As String = imagepath
    'Dim fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(filepath)
    'Read the File into a Bitmap.
    Using bmp As New Bitmap(File.OpenRead(filepath))
        Using grp As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

            'Set the Color of the Watermark text.
            Dim brush As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Gray))
            'New SolidBrush(Color.Gray)

            'Set the Font and its size.
            Dim font As Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 200, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

            Dim font1 As Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 40, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

            'Determine the size of the Watermark text.
            Dim textSize As New SizeF()
            textSize = grp.MeasureString(watermarkText, font)


            Dim textSize1 As New SizeF()
            textSize1 = grp.MeasureString(watermarkText1, font1)

            'Position the text and draw it on the image.
            ' Dim position As New Point((bmp.Width  / 2), (bmp.Height / 2))
            Dim position As New Point((bmp.Width / 2 - (CInt(textSize.Width) / 2)), (bmp.Height / 2 - (textSize.Height / 2)))
            grp.DrawString(watermarkText, font, brush, position)

            Dim position1 As New Point((bmp.Width / 2 - (CInt(textSize.Width) / 2 - 200)), (bmp.Height / 2 - (textSize.Height / 2 - 200)))
            grp.DrawString(watermarkText1, font1, brush, position1)

            Dim p As String
            p = Server.MapPath("reza" & newpath)

            bmp.Save(p, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            bmp.Dispose()

            brush.Dispose()
            font.Dispose()

            font1.Dispose()
            grp.Dispose()

            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()






        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: it sounds like `p` may be the same as `filepath` which is already open for the `bmp`.  the output filename is in use is the issue not disposing pr GC

Comment: From a code review perspective, all of your brushes and fonts need to have their own `using` statements.  Then get rid of all of the `Dispose` calls and the `GC` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the bitmap with `Using Bitmap(File.OpenRead(filepath))`, it leaves the file open. If you exit the Using block, it should close the file so you can delete it, etc. It's odd, but that's the way Windows works. If you use `Bitmap.FromStream` to load the file, the file is not left open and it will probably solve the problem.

The reason Dispose won't work is because you cannot dispose a bitmap inside the Using block. It is disposed automatically when the block is exited.